# how do i link to a specfic block in a page?

Tags: magento

I had displayed part of "latest testimonial" (textarea) on my home page, and placed a "view more" link in the end.

Now I want to link to that specific testimonial on a page when "view more" is clicked.

But I had a list of testimonials on a single testimonial page, meaning no separate detail page for each testimonial. So how can I display the specific testimonial on the page ?

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('testimonial'); ?>
```

this gives a link to my testimonial page.

Comment: i did it by <a name="<?php echo $_item[testimonial_id]; ?>"> text </a> and call it like this <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('testimonial'); ?>#<?php echo $tid; ?>"> but prob is that testimonial pages may increase to more then 1 page

Comment: mean what if i don know how many pages www.domain.com/index.php/testimonial?page=2

Answer (score 1):

First you need to provide some element IDs on your testimonials page. For example if each testimonial is in a quote:

```
<blockquote id="testimonial001">
    ...
</blockquote>
```

Or place a named anchor just before each testimonial:

```
<a id="testimonial001"></a>
...
```

Then your URL can be built [with a fragment](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters):

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('testimonial', array('_fragment'=>'testimonial001')); ?>
```

By specifying the ID through a route parameter you will override any other fragment that might get set by another module (don't know which, just know that it can happen) which is preferable to merely appending it.

Comment: i had more then one page www.domain.com/testimonial?page=2  . it doesn't link to that one

Comment: If you know which page number it will be then you can use `<?php echo $this->getUrl('testimonial', array('_query'=>array('page'=>2))); ?>>`.

Comment: sorry to say that page no is not known :(

Comment: That sounds like a whole other problem. Start a new question to ask how to find the page number. Remember to say what extension is being used or any custom code you wrote to generate the pages.

Answer (score 0):

example below should generate a link this this: http://www.example.com/testimonial#anchor

```
<?php echo getUrl('testimonial'); ?>#anchor
```

The rest you can find in this document: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp
using this example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_bookmark